# Bind gridview with List and then move items up and down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> ListOfCustomers = new List<Customer> ListOfCustomers();

ListOfCustomers.Add(new Customer{Id="1", Name="Adam", Surname="Bong"});
ListOfCustomers.Add(new Customer{Id="2", Name="Bob", Surname="Tong"});
ListOfCustomers.Add(new Customer{Id="3", Name="Colin", Surname="Wong"});
ListOfCustomers.Add(new Customer{Id="4", Name="David", Surname="Rong"});
```

I then bind it to my gridview

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
    gridCustomers.DataSource = ListOfCustomers();
    gridCustomers.DataBind();
}
```

I would now like to move the items up and down so have added two buttons on my markup. Under my RowDataBound event

```
 protected void gridCustomers_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lbMoveUp = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("MoveUpLinkButton");
            LinkButton lbMoveDown = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("MoveDownLinkButton");

            Customer c = (Customer)e.Row.DataItem;

            lbMoveUp.CommandArgument = c.Id.ToString();
            lbMoveUp.CommandName = "MoveUp";
            lbMoveDown.CommandArgument = c.Id.ToString();
            lbMoveDown.CommandName = "MoveDown";

            if (c.Id > 0)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
                {
                    lbMoveUp.Visible = false;
                }
                else if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 1 && e.Row.RowIndex <= gridCustomers.Rows.Count -1)
                {
                    lbMoveUp.Visible = true;
                    lbMoveDown.Visible = true;
                }
                else if (e.Row.RowIndex == gridCustomers.Rows.Count)
                {
                    lbMoveDown.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbMoveUp.Visible = false;
                lbMoveDown.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

What im trying to achieve is

If theres 1 item then no need to display any button as the item cant move up or down.

If theres 2 items then the first item would display the down button only and the second (or last) would display the up button only.

If there 3 or more items then the first item would display the down button only and the last would display the up button only, but all in between would display both buttons.

Im getting a range of problems using the above code and wonder if anyone could point me in the right direction?

Edit:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridCustomers" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" 
                AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" ShowHeader="true" 
                OnRowDataBound="gridCustomers_OnRowDataBound" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                OnRowCommand="gridCustomers_OnRowCommand" 
                EmptyDataText="Please add a record.">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Move Order">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="MoveUpLinkButton" runat="server"><img src="...." alt="Up"/></asp:LinkButton>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="MoveDownLinkButton" runat="server"><img src="...." alt="Down" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Your logic seems to be correct. Are you getting any exception? If no than what problem are you facing?

Comment: No exception but im getting the wrong buttons displayed. Im not sure if i have the e.Row.RowIndex and gridCustomers.Rows.Count mixed up?

Comment: Share your .aspx page code I mean gridview code or follow this article https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Moving-ASPNet-Gridview-Rows-Up-and-Down-with-Arrow-Button-click.aspx

Comment: I've added the Gridview code within the original post

Comment: You are used wrong id's of both button name (Up and Down). Use below line
` LinkButton lbMoveUp = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbMoveUp");
                LinkButton lbMoveDown = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbMoveDown");`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    List<Customer> listOfCustomers = new List<Customer>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listOfCustomers.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Adam", Surname = "Bong" });
        listOfCustomers.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Bob", Surname = "Tong" });
        listOfCustomers.Add(new Customer { Id = 3, Name = "Colin", Surname = "Wong" });
        listOfCustomers.Add(new Customer { Id = 4, Name = "David", Surname = "Rong" });

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            gridCustomers.DataSource = listOfCustomers;
            gridCustomers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void gridCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lbMoveUp = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbMoveUp");
            LinkButton lbMoveDown = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbMoveDown");

            Customer c = (Customer)e.Row.DataItem;

            lbMoveUp.CommandArgument = c.Id.ToString();
            lbMoveUp.CommandName = "MoveUp";
            lbMoveDown.CommandArgument = c.Id.ToString();
            lbMoveDown.CommandName = "MoveDown";

            if (c.Id > 0)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
                {
                    lbMoveUp.Visible = false;
                }
                else if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 1 && e.Row.RowIndex < listOfCustomers.Count - 1)
                {
                    lbMoveUp.Visible = true;
                    lbMoveDown.Visible = true;
                }
                else if (e.Row.RowIndex == listOfCustomers.Count - 1)
                {
                    lbMoveDown.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbMoveUp.Visible = false;
                lbMoveDown.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. The last row shows both buttons with 4 records but should show only the up button

Comment: @Computer, I have run this code on my machine and it's working as per your requirement. Please see attach image.

Comment: @Computer, See my updated code and it's working as per your requirement